# Dynamically add widgets on a scene through fxml or Scene builder in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder, scene

I am working on a simple BeatBox, where different sounds play depending on the checkboxes that were selected.

The program is supposed to have 256 checkboxes, displayed on a 16x16 grid. So when I build the GUI through direct code (i.e without fxml or the scene builder), I can easily create a simple loop to create the 256 checkboxes, add them to a list so that I can use them later, and add them to the grid.

I am trying to change that approach and do it with the scene builder or coding directly on the fxml file, but I can't figure out a way of doing it, and I don't even know if that is possible. Trying to figure out that, I came across this doubt: 
- Is there a way to create a list of some type of widget, populated with loads of components (for my given example, a list with 256 CheckBoxes), through fxml or scene builder, and then have a reference to the list on my Controller class?

I really don't like the idea of dragging-and-dropping 256 Checkboxes on the scene builder, or even make 256 tags on the fxml. And I think that that feature could be useful for many other cases. So if that is possible, I'd love a help on it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FXML format does not provide a way to declare elements in a loop. As *Scene Builder* is simply a [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editor for FXML files it also doesn't provide this functionality, nor does it provide a shortcut to declaring and configuring 256 elements (e.g. via a dialog or something). This is one of those cases where adding the nodes in code is the proper solution.

To do this you'll need to link your FXML file to a controller. From there you can create all 256 `CheckBox`es inside the `initialize` method. This method comes from the [`Initializable`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html) interface, though since JavaFX 8 you no longer need to actually implement the interface. Instead, you just declare a no-arg method named `initialize` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53948756/6395627)) and annotate it with `@FXML` if non-`public`.

Here's a small example:

**FXML File**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<!-- replace with your root -->
<HBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.2" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      fx:controller="com.example.Controller">

    <GridPane fx:id="grid"/>

    <!-- other elements... -->

</HBox>
```

**Controller**

```
package com.example;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class Controller {

    @FXML private GridPane grid;
    private CheckBox[][] boxes; // for access by grid coordinates

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        boxes = new CheckBox[16][16];
        for (int row = 0; row < boxes.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < boxes[0].length; col++) {
                CheckBox box = new CheckBox();
                grid.add(box, col, row);
                boxes[row][col] = box;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, I think that we all came at the conclusion that there's isn't a way of creating them directly through FXML then. And yes, doing it that way (with code) it accomplishes the task with no problems, as I said in my question. I was just wandering if that could be done in the FXML, which by the answers I'm seeing, it isn't possible. Cheers!

Comment: You're correct in that both Amarildo and I are saying you can't do this in FXML or Scene Builder. The rest of my answer is simply an example of how to do it since just saying "no, you can't do this" seems like only half an answer. The example is also in response to you saying "_So when I build the GUI through direct code (i.e without fxml or the scene builder)..._"—specifically the "_without fxml or scene builder_" part. I was simply showing you a way to do this _in combination with_ FXML. If you already knew how to do this then perhaps this answer will help others in the future.